# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string ERROR when running laravel query

Tags: laravel

I am using a query in Laravel, but when I try to dump it shows this error

'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string'

This is the query ->

```
 $staff = User::find($id);
        $departments = Department::all();
        $managers = DB::table('users')
            ->where('role', 'manager')
            ->get();

        $staffId = DB:: table('users')
                ->where('id', $id)
                ->select('deptId')
                ->get();
        
    
        $empDept = DB::table('departments')
                ->join('users','users.deptId','=','departments.id')
                ->select('department_name')
                ->where('departments.id', $staffId)
                ->orWhere('users.deptId', '=', 'departments.id')
                ->pluck('departments.department_name')
                ->first();
    
        dd($empDept);
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: `$staffId` is a Collection of stdClass objects not a single value

Comment: @lagbox what should I do in that case?

Comment: You can do several things, but you cannot say that an ID = list of ID. In that case you can use WhereIn to see if it is within a list etc, but comparing a collection with an string will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a Collection of stdClass objects to the `where` method on the query you are building. It is iterating that Collection and trying to use the values as strings but they are stdClass objects which can not be converted to strings. You should be passing a single value to the where condition:

```
$staffId = $staff->deptId;
```

Now you are getting the `deptId` value from the User object you already have instead of querying the table again.

If you really wanted to query the table again you could just ask for the single value instead of the entire record using the `value` method:

```
$staffId = DB:: table('users')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->value('deptId');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decode your data first

```
$code = json_decode($query, true);
```